# How to uncheck(untick) the jCheckBox automatically when I close its child frame?

Tags: java, jcheckbox

I am working on a Java application. The main class frame name as "a". In frame "a", there is one component - jCheckBox. So when I check(tick) this jCheckBox, it open another frame "b". I wanted to untick the jCheckBox when I close frame "b", but it seems like cannot works. Any idea how to solve this? Thanks.

Edit: However, I could close frame "b" by untick the jCheckBox in frame a (in main class frame).What I want to achieve is when I close frame "b", it should automatically uncheck the jCheckBox in frame "a". IDE show me a lot of errors after I compile my apps.

**My code:**
(In Main frame A)

```
  private void jCheckBoxInfoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
       if (jCheckBoxInfo.isSelected()) {
                System.err.println("Frame B is opened");
                b.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                System.err.println("Frame B is closed");
                frameInfo.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
```

In frame B:

```
private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {   
   boolean selected = a.jCheckBoxInfo.isSelected();
   System.err.println(selected); //To check the status of jCheckBoxInfo
   a.jCheckBoxInfo.setSelected(false);  }
```

**Output:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Win32GraphicsConfig.java:222)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:505)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
    at b.<init>(b.java:30)
    at a.<init>(a.java:36)
    at b.<init>(b.java:26)
    at a.<init>(a.java:36)
```

Comment: The stack trace looks like you're creating `b` instances from `a` constructor (or equivalent), and vice versa => stack overflow.

Comment: That is correct. It happen when I click the closing "X" button - Close the window of frame B.

Comment: The question is *why* would you create more `a` instances from `b`. The problem is the mutually recursive object construction. Just keep references to the existing frames.

Comment: In frame A, I did make a public access to class b.
Code --> public b frameInfo = new b(); 

While in frame B, I did make the similar call back to class a.
Code --> public a frameMain = new a();

I am trying to make the application automatically uncheck jCheckBoxInfo in frame a.

Comment: Hopefully by creating an instances from [a], I could uncheck the jCheckBoxInfo in frame B? While in frame a, I create an instances from [b] to open the frame b when I checked the jCheckBoxInfo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In frame A, I did make a public access to class b. Code --> public b frameInfo = new b(); While in frame B, I did make the similar call back to class a. Code --> public a frameMain = new a(); I am trying to make the application automatically uncheck jCheckBoxInfo in frame a.

That `new a()` is the problem; you're not unchecking the box in the existing frame, instead you're creating a new window and unchecking it there (which in turn results in more windows being created ad infinity; or rather until the stack overflow).

Instead you can:

1. Add the `WindowListener` while in `a` (probably using an anonymous internal class, extending `WindowAdapter`), instead of in `b`. Then you can directly refer the checkbox in `windowClosing()`. This is likely the cleanest approach as it avoids binding `b` more tightly to `a` than necesary, and keeps the visibility handling completely in `a`.
2. If the `b` frame is a dialog with `a` as the  parent window, you can get the owner window with: `getOwner()`, cast it to `a` and untick the check box there.
3. If there is no owner window (in which case see [about using multiple frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)), you can pass the `a` instance to `b`, for example as a constructor parameter:

   ```
   class b {
       final a parent;
       public b(a parent) {
           this.parent = parent;
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

   and then you can just uncheck the checkbox using the `parent` reference.
4. If `b` is an internal class of `a`, it has an implicit reference to the enclosing object, and it can be referred as `a.this`.

In any case, use a reference to the existing `a`, where from you created the `b`, instead of creating a new `a` in `b`.